# How to implement SiteEdit 2009

Tags: siteedit-2009

I am new in to using SiteEdit, I want to implement SiteEdit on a page. I have read detail on SDL LiveContent.

I did following steps

1. I have updated PT, adding SiteEdit 2009 from Building Block in Template builder and add TargettypeURI parameter
2. I published the page corresponding to that targetURI

But SiteEdit button is still not visible on my page.

Questions:

1. What I am missing in configuration side for siteEdit?
2. Do I need to make some changes in Component and CT for SiteEdit 2009?

Comment: What URL are you accessing when you expect to see the SiteEdit button? For SiteEdit 2009, the URL of your regular page and the same page in "SiteEdit mode" are different.

Comment: I accessing regular page URL. I don't know is there any different URL for SiteEdit mode . could you pls tell me how can i  know what is my "SiteEdit mode" page URL ?

Comment: After installing SiteEdit 2009 there is normally a new website added to the same server where Tridion is running (by default on port 84), you should access this site. Or, if you're using Tridion 2011 or higher, skip SE 2009 altogether and implement Experience Manager...

Answer (score 7):

When you install SiteEdit 2009, you are creating a new web site in IIS (on the same machine where your Tridion Content Manager is installed). This web site (often called the SiteEdit proxy web site) proxies incoming requests between your staging site and your Tridion server.

```
     Browser
        | (1)
    SiteEdit
      Proxy
    (3) | (2)
   +----+----+
   |         |
Tridion   Staging
Content     Web
Manager     Site
```

So in the above diagram:

1. you connect to the SiteEdit proxy web site (with a URL that identifies your web site, e.g. http://siteedit.mywebsite.com/default.aspx or http://staging.mywebsite.com:84/default.aspx)
2. the proxy requests the corresponding page from the Staging web site (e.g. http://staging.mywebsite.com/default.aspx)
3. the SiteEdit proxy parses the HTML and then contacts the Tridion Content Manager to get the necessary information about the Page and its editable Components.

This is a bit simplified (the actual process covers at least a dozen such steps IIRC), but it serves to illustrate the need to connect to a different web site when you are looking to edit content using SiteEdit 2009.